# Negation of double logic quantifiers

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

$$\forall a\forall b\ (a^{2}+4b-2=0)$$

How exactly would this be negated? would the $(a^{2}+4b-2 = 0)$ be negated twice (and as such remain the same?

For example:

$$\neg (\forall a\forall b\ (a^{2}+4b-2 =0))$$
$$\neg \forall a \neg \forall b\ (a^{2}+4b-2 =0)$$
$$\exists a \neg \forall b\ \neg (a^{2}+4b-2 =0)$$
$$\exists a \exists b\ \neg\neg(a^{2}+4b-2 =0)$$
$$\exists a \exists b\ (a^{2}+4b-2 =0)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it one step at a time - the following are equivalent.

$$\neg \forall a\forall b\ (a^{2}+4b-2=0)$$

$$\exists a\neg\forall b\ (a^{2}+4b-2=0)$$

$$\exists a\exists b\neg (a^{2}+4b-2=0)$$

$$\exists a\exists b(a^{2}+4b-2\neq0)$$

In general, you can move a negation operator through a $\forall$ quantifier by turning it into an $\exists$ quantifier, and vice versa. This is somewhat analogous to [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws); just think of $\exists$ as being kind of like $\vee$ and $\forall$ as being kind of like $\wedge$.

Comment: I don't know that $\neq$ is permissible, so it might be
$$
\exists a \exists b (\neg[a^b+4b-2=0])
$$